# In Street Fighter: The Storytelling Game, can I take my "move action" during any part of my turn?

Tags: street-fighter-rpg

It doesn't get simpler than that.

Can I attack and then move? Or do I have to move before using my attack maneuver?

I can't find a single phrase in the book that makes it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You must move before attacking, never after.**

According to World of Darkness: Combat, you must to take your move action or move maneuver before you use your attack maneuver. Since this book has pretty much the same combat rules found in Street Fighter, and is based on the same Storytelling system, I'm pretty sure it works the same way.

In other words, you only move before your attack, ever after it.

Thanks @Jessa for letting me know about the World of Darkness: Combat. It is just like you said: *"My understanding is that it re-uses many of the detailed combat mechanics from SF"*. It really does.

Comment: Without having the book in front of me, I can only give the generic warning of "They changed the system every time they used it, so proceed with caution"

Comment: @Tritium21 do you mean the system for Street Fighter?

Comment: I mean the Storytelling System.  Every time it is used in the oWoD, it was changed and mutated a little - usually in the combat rules in subtle ways.  So what is published for in WoD:Combat barely applies to WoD, let alone a game not in the core product lines at the time.

Comment: @Tritium21 Word of Darkness: Combat is from the second edition of the old World of Darkness. That was when Street Fighter, the storytelling game was published. They both use the same set of basic rules, including maneuver cards, therefore I'm pretty sure this comparison is more than just fine.